# Get data from 3 database tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables

1. `Users` - columns `id, userName,`...
2. `Comment` - columns `id, text, userId, roomId`
3. `CommentRate` - columns `userId, commmentId`

`CommentRate` table contain `userId`'s that liked this comment identified by `commentId`.

I want to select all comments (`id, text, roomId, userId, userName, []ListOfLikes`) from `Comment` table by `roomId` where `[]ListOfLikes` should contain `userId, userName`.

Comment: I cant read what you wrote, please format your question and make it clear

Comment: can i select list that one of it's column is list ?

Comment: No you cant select a row which one of column is list, all should be values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer the same table ( `USER` in this case) more times with different join criteria using aliases, but It is not possible to convert values in field names. This statement will extract all that you need, but repeating rows and not adding columns:

```
SELECT C.ID, C.TEXT, C.ROOMID, U.USERNAME, U2.USERNAME 
FROM  COMMENT C 
INNER JOIN COMMENTRATE CR ON C.ID = CR.COMMENTID
INNER JOIN  USERS U ON C.USERID = U.ID
INNER JOIN  USERS U2 ON CR.USERID = U2.ID
WHERE U.USERNAME IN ('username1', 'username2')
ORDER BY C.ROOMID
```

If you want to filter by users that likes, you could replace `U` with `U2` in the `WHERE` line of code.